# android holo theme background

Tags: android, background, themes

I would like to know, if I can get the background that is displayed when using android's holo theme, as a drawable? (you know, the dark black and blue background that is displayed for 3.0+) I need to use it as a drawable, so if someone knows if this can be done, please let me know..

[image]

Sorry, but I forgot to mention that this is displayed on a tablet device, not sure about phones.

Comment: can you give an examplescreenshot perhaps? I dont know which Background you mean. In Holo Theme there is nothing like that(as far as I know)... And also that's a non programmatic question.

Comment: I added a screenshot. My question is, can I get this background's resource as a drawable? maybe it is not possible.. but worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible, your best bet is to look in the android .jar for 3.0 (which can be downloaded using ADT in Eclipse)
The image may be found in  /drawable/drawable-hdpi or possibly somewhere within /drawable

If not, it likely is only possible to find in the source.

Comment: I will try the .jar, because the source for android honeycomb is not and never will be available. thank you for your advice

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that niggle with 3.0 ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Location of the files

**Holo-Dark:**

> /path_to_sdk/platforms/android-version/data/res/drawable/background_holo_dark.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff000000"
            android:endColor="#ff272d33"
            android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**Holo-Light:**

> /path_to_sdk/platforms/android-version/data/res/drawable/background_holo_light.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ffe8e8e8"
            android:endColor="#ffffffff"
            android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

## Make your own

Put the following code in *res/drawable/background.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
    >
<gradient 
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="#ff020202"
    android:endColor="#ff272D33"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Add the background reference to your parent viewgroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
```

Play around with the values until you get the desired effect.

Comment: I needed a drawable because I am using renderscript, but thank u for the suggestion, i will definitely try this out, for other purposes maybe.

Comment: I have no knowledge of renderscript, but if you inflate that shape you will get a ShapeDrawable which extends from Drawable

Answer (score 0):

Here, perhaps this would help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I needed the background as a drawable, to use it in .java classes. I know that you can apply a theme for the activity, but the problem that I am having is that I am using renderscript in my application, so the theme's background is never shown on the RSSurfaceView.